# Azure Release Pipeline approval from jira ticket

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jira, azure-releases

I have an azure pipeline that triggers on a branch commit to build the content of the branch and automatically create a release.
I tried to add the `Pre-Deployement Approvals` in the release stage conditions, and this sends a notification in slack channel where i can approve the releases.

This workflow works just fine. Today i wanted to experiment with jira and azure devops, so i intalled the integration `Azure pipeline jira integration` to keep track of the releases that belong to a specific ticket. This is the extensione i am using:

`https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira`

This works well and i can see all the releases in the ticket issue. But i was wondering if there is any way to enable the approval on a release and when this trigger to send a notification in jira to be approved instead of slack.

Thank you so much for anyone who can point me on the right direction if any.